# How can I unstick gear on a clock

Tags: stuck

This may be a little OT for a "Home Improvement" site but it's -- sort of -- home repair so I hope I can get some pointers.

I have a [Golden Hour Clock](http://www.roger-russell.com/jeffers/jefhour.htm) which doesn't keep time.

The minute hand is mounted to the backing glass and moves through a full circle each hour.

But the hour hand doesn't move smoothly.  It is attached through a series of gears to the minute hand in the front and a weight in the back.  As the minute hand moves, it tries to take the hour hand with it but the weight holds it back and the result is the hour hand moving at the correct pace.

Except the gears on mine seem to stick partway around and the weight gets carried up with the minute hand rather than hanging down.

I found some directions for repairing the clock but they all assume that the clock *slips*, not sticks as mine does.  I've looked at the gears to see if there is some obstruction or missing tooth but neither seems to be true.  I saw one suggestion that old, sticky oil might gum up the gears with a recommendation to soak in mineral spirits.  I tried that, too, and didn't get any improvement.  (I only soaked the gears for 10-15 minutes.  Maybe that wasn't long enough.)

I'm handy -- I can do plumbing and carpentry and household electrical work -- but mechanics (gears and such) is beyond my experience.

Any thoughts on getting these gears to move smoothly?  TIA.